# Passing a Click Event to Child

Tags: reactjs

I have a click event to show a popup window in the parent and need to pass it down to List child and then to Item child and then to List child. When user clicks the Link component, it opens the pop up. It does not work right now, "TypeError: onCourseSelect is not a function. My code is below. Please help!

```
    App.js
onCourseSelect=(course)=>{
    this.setState({selectedCourse:course 
                ,showPopup:true             
    });
  };
<List course={course} onCourseSelect={this.onCourseSelect} />

List.js
const List=(course,onCourseSelect)=>{
return(
<Item key={course.ID} course={course} onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect}  />)}
)}

Item.js
const Item=({course, onCourseSelect})=>{
  return(<Link onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect(course)} course={course}></Link> )

}

Link.js
const Link=({course, onCourseSelect})=>{

    return (
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="View More" onClick={onCourseSelect(course)} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Item.js you wrote `onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect(course)}` which should be rather `onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect}` as you just have to pass this as a prop to child component where it can be called. The course is passed as a separate prop in  component.

On `<input>` you can then do, `onClick = {()=>{ onCourseSelect(course) }}`.

Writing `onClick = { onCourseSelect(course) }` will call the method onCourseSelect on each re-render.

`App.js`

```
onCourseSelect=(course)=>{
    this.setState({
        selectedCourse:course,
        showPopup:true             
    });
};
<List course={course} onCourseSelect={this.onCourseSelect} />
```

`List.js`

```
const List=({course,onCourseSelect})=>{
return(
<Item key={course.ID} course={course} onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect}  />)}
)}
```

`Item.js`

```
const Item=({course, onCourseSelect})=>{
  return(<Link onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect} course={course}></Link> )

}
```

`Link.js`

```
const Link=({course, onCourseSelect})=>{

    return (
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="View More" onClick={()=> onCourseSelect(course)} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code above in Link.js and the error message is  "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

Comment: there was also a change in Item.js. You wrote onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect(course)}` which should be  rather `onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect}` as you just have to pass this as a prop to child component where it can be called.